# What to do if a user embeds improper words in their code?

Tags: discussion, flags

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753255) question I believe OP is using improper words as function name. I know the general action of improper words in context is just replace the words. But the problem is, if they are embedded in code, and I'm not sure if replacing them may cause other problems such as compile errors, what can I do? Should we flag this if I can't replace the words?

Comment: It's easier to edit it out, honestly.  I can take care of it.  But I'm concerned that someone else may be offended by something else left behind in there...

Comment: You should be aware that `faggot` has *real* meanings beyond trying to be an insult to homosexuals. So it's not *necessarily* improper. I'd probably be less than impressed if I was a fundamentalist Christian that both that and `Jesus` were used as function names but, given Jesus is a pretty common name, it may not be meant that way. Still, if it offends you, flag it as offensive. I would say the function names are stupid since they don't really give the intent of the function but I don't (quite) find that offensive.

Comment: Of course, if I was a *non* fundamentalist Christian, I'd probably turn the other cheek. Unfortunately that tends to just get you slapped on the *other* side of the face so it may not be a tenable strategy long term :-)

Comment: But unclear function names *are* offensive to me!

Comment: @Jongware: Ditto mostly, hence my `(quite)` qualifier :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this scenario, a flag isn't the best choice since there's nothing that a moderator can do that the rest of the community can't.  Not just that, but in hindsight, we'd be yelling a person who hasn't come back to the community in very nearly a year.

You can certainly suggest an edit since you have less than 2K rep.  In your case, I would have explained in the edit revision box why you made the decision to edit it out, and you'd also have to go back to edit out the other answers that may be using it, which can be a bit complicated if you don't have full edit rights.

In this case, I would say that it's an isolated occurrence, edit it out and move on.  If you did notice a trend with this user's posts and their constant habit of posting offensive content, I'd say that's when you'd want to get a moderator involved.